# How to find the direct descendants of a non-root element with CSS selectors in Selenium?

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I'm trying to reuse a found WebElement for the `<table>` below to search for its descendants and direct descendants:

```html
<html>
    ...
    <table id="tbl">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>foo</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
            <tr><td><button class="btnDefault"/></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
</html>
```

This table might contain nested tables - or it might not, I just don't want to wade through the whole thing, I'd rather use a more specific selector that's guaranteed to do what I want. And some of the elements I need don't have reasonable IDs, I want to look for them using the selectors:

```css
#tbl1 > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child > div
#tbl1 > tbody > tr > td > button.btnDefault
```

To make the code less repetitive and maybe faster, I'd like to cache the `<table>` element:

```cs
var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbl"));
var div = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector("> tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child > div"));
var button = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector("> tbody > tr > td > button.btnDefault"));
```

This blows up as an invalid CSS selector on the second and third query. Which is correct, but then again, standard CSS syntax is not meant to search from a specific scope. Is there some sort of construct that could be used as the root of the query here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to use the pseudo-class `:scope` to refer to the current element.

This pseudo-class is present in the [Selectors Level 4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-scope-pseudo) and is currently supported by Firefox and Chrome. But some browsers might not support it.

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tbl"));
var div = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector(":scope > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child > div"));
var button = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector(":scope > tbody > tr > td > button.btnDefault"));
```

Be aware that using strong dependencies like "immediate child" usually leads to a brittle selector which will increase the cost of maintenance of your tests.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! The codebase is unfortunately a legacy monstrosity, I'll take brittle tests with false positives over none at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the page class, why not u use to :

```
public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "btnDefault")] 
private IWebElement button { get; set; }
```

You will get the button as WebElement when you instantiate the class.

Comment: I’m not really sure how this at all resolves my issue, beyond being maybe a mild clarity improvement. (Probably not because there’s more than one such buttons, and I’m testing a multi-step workflow that involves an AJAX popup that is also multi-step.)

Answer (score 0):

because you're calling FindElement from the table element, then this should work:

```
var div = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child > div"));
var button = table.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr > td > button.btnDefault"));
```

That removed the ">" at the start.

Comment: That just fixes the syntax issue, but doesn't guarantee that the `tbody` that matches will be a direct descendant of the table. That said I'm not realizing that's pointless, because `FindElement` should always grab the first found element anyway, which when searching from a `table` will be its corresponding `tbody`.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem.  I fiddled around with caching 'table#tbl > tbody' which with minor change for 'div' would work, but that didn't get me very far with 'button'.  It wouldn't help change performance, but to reduce repetition, you could create a method on your page to do your interactions with these elements (assuming you're using Page Object Model)

Answer (score 0):

IF you have multiple button with same class name. When I will suggest to identify the cell where the button exists. May be the following code will work:

```
public IWebDriver WebDriver { get; set; }

IWebElement tableElement = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id(tableName));
            IWebElement tbodyElement = tableElement.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
            List<IWebElement> rows = new List<IWebElement>(tbodyElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")));
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                if (row.GetAttribute("row") != "-1" && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetAttribute("row"))))
                {
                    List<IWebElement> cells = new List<IWebElement>(row.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));
                    if (cells.Count != 0)
                    {
                        if (cells[0].Text == columnName) //Identify the cell, may use other attribute
                        {
                            IWebElement btn = cells[0].FindElement(By.ClassName("btnDefault")) as IWebElement;
                            return btn;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This seems like it does the equivalent of querying for `table tbody tr td`, so even less specific than what I already have.