# How to use a parent selector within a relative css selector in selenium python

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm going to try my best to explain the problem.

This question is about selenium in Python. Consider this example:

```py
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='overflow: hidden;'] > div > div:nth-child(3)"):
    player = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '> div:first-child > span').text
```

Obviously, this second line is wrong, you can't start a CSS query with `>`. However, that brings me to the question at hand, how exactly *would* I do something like this? How would I select all divs that are a direct child of the `row` element? I know you can use XPaths to achieve this, however, those are kind of a pain to work with (at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get **all** the child elements of the parent element with Selenium and CSS Selectors you can simply directly apply the `find_element` on specific web element (node) as following:

```py
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='overflow: hidden;'] > div > div:nth-child(3)"):
    player = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div:first-child > span').text
```

And in case you  want to find the first **direct** child of the parent element `:scope` pseudo element can be used.
This will give you the first direct child of `row` node matching the `div:first-child > span` locator:

```py
for row in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='overflow: hidden;'] > div > div:nth-child(3)"):
    player = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ':scope > div:first-child > span').text
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097489/3485434) for more explanations.

Comment: `some_element div:first-child > span` is **not** the same thing as `some_element > div:first-child > span`. Without the >, the selector means search for **any** div that is the first child within the entire row, rather than the direct children of the row.

Comment: of course, and I got different results than when I typed the full selector into chrome devtools. I already understand that doing `row.find_element` automatically makes the selector relative, but my question is how we can use `>` at the beginning of a relative CSS selector

Comment: I found the solution. Tested it. Looks like this is what you looked for. See the linked answer for more explanations.

Comment: You are welcome! I learned something new by this too :)