# Is there a way to identify a web element selenium using an already identified element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, element

I have an element identified using python selenium.

Below is the code:

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class="s-topbar--logo js-gps-track"])
```

Is there a way to identify a web element in python selenium using an already identified element? using any method possible. A child element, or a sibling element. It could be using xpath, css_selector, or any way. Above is just an example code, and have used xpath only for example purpose.

Comment: Your question is unclear. We definitely can locate element based on other element. It can be child element, parent element, sibling element etc. What exactly you asking about?

Comment: I know about what you are trying to tell. Which part of the question is not clear? From the above code I have an element captured in a variable called "element". I want to capture it's child element using this variable.

Comment: OK. What do we know about the child element? Tag name, some attribute value etc. Is it direct child or not?

Comment: Anything bro. Just anything.. You can consider any attribute you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find child element based on parent element instance and some child element attributes similarly to how we locating regular element. This can be done both with XPath and CSS Selectors.
For example, let's say the child element is `div` with `id=child`.
Locating this element with XPath will be as following:

```py
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
parent_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='s-topbar--logo js-gps-track']")
child_element = parent_element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@id='child']")
```

The only 2 important changes here are:

1. We apply `find_element` method on `parent_element` object, not on the `driver` object.
2. The XPath is starting with a dot `.` to make the XPath relative to the current node.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74295106/3485434) how to do that with CSS Selectors or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74353422/3485434) for more explanations about XPath relative locators.